# Magento 2: Deploy Production mode with fresh install

Tags: backend, magento2.2.6, deploy, production-mode

I am working with MAGE2.2.6. It is a fresh install.

Before I opened magento for the first time. I changed from default to Production mode, in the etc.php file. I also cleared my var/cash and var/page_cash folders.

But I just get the spinning wheels of loading for any content: Product, Catalog, Pages, Widgets...

How can I deploy Production without using the CLI?

Is that the only way to do it?

I prefer to do it from the back-end if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command in CLI

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:production
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't change the mode from admin.

You can deploy to production mode in two ways

1.You can enable it using command

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

2.Open the app/etc/env.php
Change the content 'MAGE_MODE' => 'default' to 'MAGE_MODE' => 'production',

Run the below commands after this.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```